PGFplots: problem with fill between influencing axis line width
I'm using MacTeX 2024 on a MacBook Pro. While creating a Beamer presentation with the moloch theme, I have run across the following problem. I have a PGF plot that does exactly what I want it to do (first frame of the MWE below). When I add a shaded region using fill between (second frame of the MWE below), the axis line width is reduced from the desired 0.75pt to some smaller value. Note the tick mark line width is not affected. I would like the axis line width to stay at the defined 0.75pt. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance for any wisdom you can impart.
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{4477AA}
\definecolor{mDarkTeal}{HTML}{23373b}

\usetheme[block=fill]{moloch}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plot without the problem}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    height              = 7cm, 
    width               = 10cm,
    axis x line         = bottom,
    x axis line style   = {line cap=rect},
    axis y line         = left,
    y axis line style   = {line cap=rect},
    line width          = 0.75pt,
    axis line style     = {-},
    xtick               = {0,12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96},
    xtick align         = inside,
    xmin                = -2,
    xmax                = 96,
    ytick               = {0,1,2,3},
    ytick align         = inside,
    ymin                = 0,
    ymax                = 3,
    major tick length   = 0.1cm,
    tick style          = {line width=0.75pt, color=mDarkTeal},
    enable tick line clipping = false,
    ]
\addplot [name path=first, line width=0.75, blue] coordinates {(0,0) (24,2) (48,1) (96,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plot with the problem}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    height              = 7cm, 
    width               = 10cm,
    axis x line         = bottom,
    x axis line style   = {line cap=rect},
    axis y line         = left,
    y axis line style   = {line cap=rect},
    line width          = 0.75pt,
    axis line style     = {-},
    xtick               = {0,12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96},
    xtick align         = inside,
    xmin                = -2,
    xmax                = 96,
    ytick               = {0,1,2,3},
    ytick align         = inside,
    ymin                = 0,
    ymax                = 3,
    major tick length   = 0.1cm,
    tick style          = {line width=0.75pt, color=mDarkTeal},
    enable tick line clipping = false,
    ]
\addplot [name path=first, line width=0.75, blue] coordinates {(0,0) (24,2) (48,1) (96,0)};
\path [name path=baseline] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\addplot [blue!20] fill between [of=first and baseline, soft clip={domain=24:48}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Here is the frame without shading (everything looks good):

Here is the frame with shading and with the problem (note diminished axis line width):


Proposed solution
Condense the two separate <x/y> axis line style into the one axis line style option (because you're using the same options for both anyways), and change the line width of the axis lines separately in those style options. Feels a bit ad hoc, but it works so... :)
Code
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{4477AA}
\definecolor{mDarkTeal}{HTML}{23373b}

\usetheme[block=fill]{moloch}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plot without the problem}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    height              = 7cm, 
    width               = 10cm,
    axis x line         = bottom,
    x axis line style   = {line cap=rect},
    axis y line         = left,
    y axis line style   = {line cap=rect},
    line width          = 0.75pt,
    axis line style     = {-},
    xtick               = {0,12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96},
    xtick align         = inside,
    xmin                = -2,
    xmax                = 96,
    ytick               = {0,1,2,3},
    ytick align         = inside,
    ymin                = 0,
    ymax                = 3,
    major tick length   = 0.1cm,
    tick style          = {line width=0.75pt, color=mDarkTeal},
    enable tick line clipping = false,
    ]
\addplot [name path=first, line width=0.75, blue] coordinates {(0,0) (24,2) (48,1) (96,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plot with the problem}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    height              = 7cm, 
    width               = 10cm,
    axis x line         = bottom,
    % x axis line style   = {line cap=rect},
    axis y line         = left,
    % y axis line style   = {line cap=rect},
    line width          = 0.75pt,
    axis line style     = {-, line width=0.75pt, line cap=rect},  % Changed this one!
    xtick               = {0,12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96},
    xtick align         = inside,
    xmin                = -2,
    xmax                = 96,
    ytick               = {0,1,2,3},
    ytick align         = inside,
    ymin                = 0,
    ymax                = 3,
    major tick length   = 0.1cm,
    tick style          = {line width=0.75pt, color=mDarkTeal},
    enable tick line clipping = false,
    ]
\addplot [name path=first, line width=0.75, blue] coordinates {(0,0) (24,2) (48,1) (96,0)};
\path [name path=baseline] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\addplot [blue!20] fill between [of=first and baseline, soft clip={domain=24:48}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Images


Thanks BrightBulb123! Simple and solves the issue.
